# Trying to build a real flying saucer, send help!

Tags: electricity, electromagnetism, radioactivity

It is a cone shape saucer-like craft, acting as a giant resonator. The upper deck is made out of paramagnetic materials, such as zinc and magnesium, but the lower deck chamber is made out of a diamagnetic material such as bismuth.

[image]

The emitters that are located in the lower deck of the craft are stacked copper discs acting as an electrical generator encased in a cylindrical dielectric material, which propagates focused electromagnetic radiation that reflects off the grid of the lower deck plate, creating a large electromagnetic standing wave chamber.
[image]

At the top of the craft is an RF transmitter which propagates waves down through the waveguide rod to the lower deck chamber. The transmitter sends 90°-180° spin-echo pulses to the lower deck chamber. This phases the diamagnetic chamber from demagnetization to magnetization, pulsing the chamber from a diamagnet to a ferromagnet. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_echo

The electrical emitters act as a mass driver, such as from a coil gun. The resonance chamber is full of diamagnetic standing wave polarity, which repels against the applied area of the emitters, which turn the area into a ferromagnet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_driver

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun

The video just shows what I mean by the geometry of the reflecting waves in the lower deck chamber. https://youtu.be/JAuUsOwrenA

Would a flying saucer built in this fashion be plausible?

Comment: Yes, and? There is no question mark in this question. What is it that you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking: is it possible?
Or what alterations would make it possible?

Comment: Depends on what you're asking?  It isn't clear whether this design _emits_ anything.  If it does, then [directed energy propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEEP-IN) is a thing.  If it doesn't, then no, it is impossible under current understandings of physics.  But you've also got "gravity amplifiers" in the image, which are definitely not a thing.

Comment: The top image is just an example I've taken to try and rationalize the theory.

There is no way to create an upward torque by dephasing the diamagnet into a ferromagnet?

Comment: No.  That would be a reactionless drive, which is not a thing that is allowed in physics as we understand it (unless you warp space).  Now, it's sufficient technobabble that you can use it in a story and most people won't question it, but if you want "how does my reactionless drive work IRL", the answer is "it does not".

Comment: Conservation of momentum holds in electromagnetism, so you can't cause a ship to get a momentum boost upwards using EM forces unless something gets an equal and opposite momentum boost in the opposite direction (whether EM waves exhaust of some kind or masses shot out of a coilgun or the earth underneath the saucer getting a downward push from some kind of EM interaction with the saucer).

Comment: @Darkorse Sure, if you ignore the current laws of physics and/or rely on alien technology not yet invented.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Which it does. When the small applied diamagnetic becomes ferromagnetic, the outer shell emits standing bands of electromagnetic waves through the applied ferromagnetic area. The standing bands create half a wavelength just outside the craft, which immediately pushes against the rest of the diamagnet of the lower deck plate. If it was on the ground, the standing waves outside the underbelly would levitate the craft because it would create a staircase of quarter wavelengths below it. Here is a video demonstration to show you what I mean: https://youtu.be/XpNbyfxxkWE?t=178

Comment: Why the commitment to a disc shape? If you allow for the fact that your 'drive' produces thrust (albeit via handwavium physics) then you can use virtually any shape you want. As it stands the disc shape wastes space that could be given over to crew, cargo service spaces and other things.

Comment: Bear in mind that "standing waves" are not stationary, their peaks just remain stationary.  So assuming all that handwavium actually created EMR outside the craft, you'd be projecting megawatts of energy.

Comment: @Mon Because the saucer shape acts both as a resonator, such as a speaker, to propagate high volume wavelengths.

Comment: So simply curve the rear of the ship to act as the 'resonator'. The volume above that can be adapted as required.

Comment: "The standing bands create half a wavelength just outside the craft, which immediately pushes against the rest of the diamagnet of the lower deck plate. If it was on the ground, the standing waves outside the underbelly would levitate" Standing waves are just a sum of traveling waves of various frequencies according to Fourier decomposition. So is this is a form of rocket whose only exhaust is light waves, and which you want to accelerate a massive ship at an acceleration of 1 g or more in a vacuum? That would require massively energetic waves, like those made in matter/antimatter reactions.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, it would need lots of power, that's why not only is there 3 electric emitters with multiple power generating discs, but the entire lower chamber reservoir is one giant emitter itself. The changing magnetic fields inside it radiate a massive electric field outside it, which also create a giant magnetic field around it. I don't exactly know the physics algebra behind the power generation, but it would be massive, relative to its propulsion.

Comment: It would also be hugely destructive to any part of the planet from which it was taking off.  If you're fine with this, that's not a disqualifier, but anyone hoping for a close encounter of the third kind would be vaporized.

Answer (score 3):

**No**

- Your diagram points to objects titled "gravity amplifier head" and "gravity amplifier." No such things exist. We believe we can detect a gravity wave. We certainly cannot create artificial gravity. So the whole deal's off on those two titles alone.
- If you're thinking about moving via electromagnetism, the strength of those fields (given how weak the Earth's electromagnetic field is) would be catastrophically enormous. The power plant needed to create that force would overwhelm the force. Rail guns work because the power plant is not being moved along with the projectile. In fact, it's part of the mass the magnetic coils push against the throw the projectile. Basically, you're asking if you can launch yourself into space by pointing a big enough firearm at the ground and pulling the trigger. The answer's no (the ejected mass is minuscule compared to the mass you're trying to move).
- Finally, even if you could overcome bullets #1 and #2, current materials science would make this craft so heavy that it would never move. The copper alone (given the energy pulsing through it) would weigh tons and tons and tons.

Comment: I mean.. A rocket is just a really over engineered flamethrower that someone has aimed at the floor. This UFO hasn’t got any chance of working though. +1

Comment: With enough guns, you can totally get enough lift to gain height, briefly. Not enough to break the Karman line though. https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/

Comment: @JohnDvorak Hah! Leave it to XKCD to show such an oddball fact as this.

Answer (score 3):

The description of the flying saucer's propulsion system comes across as a contradictory mix and match of different physical and engineering concepts.

I'm not sure if this is a version of something like the pseudoscientific [Dean drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean_drive) or whether the propulsion system, as proposed, is a kind of electromagnetic radiation rocket. Dean drives can be considered nonsensical and impractical. Just plain bad science.

However, if the flying saucer is using electromagnetic radiation instead of reaction mass, then it's basically our old friend, the photon rocket.

Assuming it is a photon rocket it is possible to discuss its practicality. if the electromagnetic radiation is only radio-frequency, then the thrust it will generate will be microscopic. The acceleration will be so small and negligible that the flying saucer won't budge. Earth's gravity will be many orders of magnitude greater than the acceleration. Only the noise of the engines would give any indication it was trying to lift-off. Yes that means it will be about a millionth of Earth's gravity. The flying saucer is grounded.

If the photon rocket operated on the principles, as described, in the question, then the radiation needs be extremely high frequency. With wavelengths far, far shorter than radio-frequency waves. This means at least x-rays and preferably gamma-rays. The amount of power for a photon rocket to generate sufficient acceleration to blast-off from planet Earth will literally vaporize the lower half of the flying saucer.

A propulsion system that can only destroy the vessel it is trying to propel is neither practical nor plausible.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I was studying and evaluating the Dean drive and the photon rocket.

My design is neither. Mine uses acoustic-electromagnetic waves against the inner shell to superimpose the outer shell, while also using a pulse frequency to flip the paired electrons of the diamagnet into a 180° inversion spin echo. The EM waves flip the paired electron spins of the diamagnet upsidedown in and back and forth procession against its surface, creating a traveling wave of magnetic moment reflecting off the diamagnet.

Comment: The more power applied from the EM generator, the more force of the magnetic moment against the diamagnet. 
There are standing waves inside the resonator being reflected back against the emitter, but only to create more powerful traveling magnetic waves to reflect off the diamagnet from the outer shell of the underbelly.

Comment: @Darkorse The energy density of the EM radiation has to be so high the flying saucer will either melt or vaporize itself. Yes it is effectively photon rocket because the radiation field has to be high enough to generate thrust. This flying saucer sounds more like a giant microwave oven than a propulsion system..

Comment: Diamagnetism is superconduction, and applying energy to a superconductor doesn't lose energy efficacy to heat as drastically as you might think.

Comment: @Darkorse I know about superconductors. But I wasn't even thinking about that. Re-reading your question I don't see how the flying saucer is intended to move or what would make it move, which I assume is what flying saucers are meant to do, or is this simply a flying saucer-shaped electromagnetic resonator?